# Search an entire dataframe for a variable and return slice of the first occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search

I am searching my dataframe for few variables and want the indices for the first occurrence of each variable.

Sample data:

[image]

So, I want the numbers from column 4 corresponding to the first occurrence of a row value. For example: 'Out of pocket' in columns 'Level 1' or first occurrence of 'Medicaid' in 'Level 2'. This code worked for :

```
    idx = (df['Level 1'] == 'Out of pocket').idxmax()
```

But is there a way to do this without specifying the column that I want pandas to look for in. Rather search the whole dataframe for the first occurrence.

Comment: can you add `print (df["Level 1"].head())` to your question. It is difficult to identify your problem like this

Comment: Not sure if the condition in your `for` should be `!=` or `==`. Probably the reason why it returns 0 and _breaks_

Comment: I made a few edits to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [iterrows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to access both the index and values of each row.

Creating a dummy data frame 
`df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a', '!'], [3, 'b', '?'], [5, 'c', '#'], [7, 'c', '#']], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])` which looks like:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   a   !
1   3   b   ?
2   5   c   #
3   7   c   #
```

we can write a for loop with [iterrows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) and check the values of the row, in this case that column B is equal to 'c' and column C is equal to '#', and print the index of the first occurrence like so:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row.B == 'c') & (row.C == '#'):
        print(index)
        break
```

which will return us: `2`.

or specifically for you:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['Level 1'] == 'Health Insurance') & (row['Level 2'] == 'Medicare'):
        print(index)
        break
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit: Not needing to specify the column name:**

In order to not need to specify the column name we can loop through the values in each row. I've wrapped this in a function as it's the only way I know of breaking from nested loops, but I'm sure this could be improved.

```
def look_for_word(word='Medicare', df=df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for val in row:
            if val == word:
                return df['YOUR FOURTH COLUMN NAME'].iloc[index]

print(look_for_word(word='Medicare', df=df))
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it work by specifying the column name I want it to search for a particular variable. But I was wondering if it was possible to do so without specifying the column name. I made a few edits to my original question to be more clear..

Comment: It's less efficient as we're having to read every value, but the edit I've just made should get you what you're after :)

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked! Yes I understand it is inefficient, but my data is real messy. Instead of having to breakdown into different columns, rename column names I can now search along the original, indented original version.